# Daemon process cannot be accessed by this WSGI application: /mod.wsgi

Tags: python, django, apache, mod-wsgi, httpd.conf

Why do I get this error?

```
Daemon process called 'dom_server' cannot be accessed by this WSGI application: /home/stakkit/webapps/dom_server/dom-fisica.wsgi
```

The **dom-fisica.wsgi** file:

```
import os
import sys
#sys.path.append('/home/stakkit/webapps/dom_server')
sys.path.append('/home/stakkit/webapps/dom_server/osqa')
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'osqa.settings_fisica'
import django.core.handlers.wsgi
application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()
```

This is my **httpd.conf** http://pastebin.com/dQfq1RTN

Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Move the WSGIDaemonProcess outside of the VirtualHost to global scope.

You can only reach across VirtualHost's like you are if it is a 80/443 pair for he same site.